# How to change Laravel PasswordLess Login?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-8.2

I am creating laravel password less login with the help of package https://github.com/grosv/laravel-passwordless-login the issue is the url that is being sent to my mail look like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/magic-login/9?expires=1697296783&redirect_to=%2Fdashboard&user_type=app-models-user&signature=03697a62320547ba411f14a806e12cf528625c8908cdeeea2083797382c23e77 where login/9 this 9 is the id of users table, which I dont want to show rather it can show something else like any random number which we can encrypt and decrypt ir maybe we can use some random number in users table and can place that in place of showing id, also user_type=app-models-user this gives the idea of model which I am using I also want to cut that part from url. Does anybody knows how to do that?

I did tried to remove the uid and user_type from the url but it throws error to have them.